# Bootstrap modal in joomla 3.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, joomla3.1

How to use Bootstrap modal in Joomla 3.1 ? I have Bootstrap loaded and when I try to initialise

```
 $('#confirmDelete').modal();
```

my modal window I get  `$(...).modal is not a function`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way I have found is to use the *data attribute*, data-toggle="modal". An example would be:

```
<a href="#my-modal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn">Launch modal</a>
```

Comment: This is using the "old" MooTools modal. This works in Joomla 2.5 and 3.x, but will probably stop working in 4.0.

Comment: My comment was primarily aimed at people reading it now (2017) - there are two ways of doing it with Joomla 3.x: with MooTools (your solution) or jQuery (see Irfan's answer). The MooTools solution will stop working rather soonish, so people should probably stop using it *even if* they are currently targeting Joomla 3.x. The only reason to still use MooTools is if you were to also target Joomla 2.5 which I hope nobody does anymore

Comment: @Hazzit I figured and sorry if I came across a little short with my comment. I gave up on Joomla altogether around the time I posted this and now only use Wordpress for my projects for a number of reasons but mainly things like it's use of Moo and the general complexity of things.

Answer (score 5):

If someone is looking for loading external url in Bootstrap Modal window in Joomla 3 below code will help-

```
$name = "myModal";
$html = '<a href="#modal-' . $name.'" data-toggle="modal" class="btn">Launch modal</a>';
$params = array();
$params['title']  = "test";
$params['url']    = "http://localhost/";
$params['height'] = 400;
$params['width']  = "100%";
echo $html .= JHtml::_('bootstrap.renderModal', 'modal-' . $name, $params);
```

Comment: Also closeButton is supposed to default to true but I found no way to get a close button so far.

Comment: @landed: It shows close button by default. for footer close button you need to add custom html as footer key of $params array.

Comment: In fact it was my joomlart template that was incorrectly namespaced- cowboys.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a modal link to an external page, not run on pageload but only when you click the link. You can use this:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.modal');
```

and

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&tmpl=component" class="modal" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 600, y: 450}}">your link</a>
```

Comment: This is using the "old" MooTools modal. This works in Joomla 2.5 and 3.x, but will probably stop working in 4.0.